# Value price of Bond

Tags: finance

*Hi, can you help me with this exercise ? I'm good in maths but don't understand these financial problems. I would be grateful for any help*

One morning, Mr. Kowalski purchased a two-year bond with the face value of $1,000, the coupon rate qual to 10% (coupon payable at the end of each period of one year) and the average annual yield (YTM) being 12%.

Additionally he bought ten-year bond with the face value of $1,000, the coupon rate equal to 10% (coupon payable at the end of each period of one year) and the average annual yield (YTM) being 12%

It was unexpectedly announced in the afternoon that the central bank bad increased base inerest rates. Therefore, yields to maturity on the bond market increased; the average annual YTM on the bond purchased by Mr. Kowalski reached 14%. Calculate the price of the bond purchased by Kowalski and the price for which he could sell it in the afternoon (assume that transaction costs equal zero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

YTM $=12$% $=  r$

Coupon $= 10$% of Facevalue $= 100 = C$

Annual payment of coupon in arrears

Maturity amount and the Face Value $= 1000 = M$

Time to Maturity $= T$

Give this,

Price of the Bond $P = \frac{C}{(1+r)^1} + \frac{C}{(1+r)^2}+\cdots + \frac{C+M}{(1+r)^T}$

Apply this formula for Bond 1 and Bond 2 with $T_1 = 2$ and $T_2 = 10$

Price of the Bond 1 $=  966.20$

Price of the Bond 2 $=  887.00$

In the afternoon after the there has been an interest rate hike, r becomes equal to $14$%

Remainder of the numbers remain the same and now compute the price and the results are

Price of the Bond 1 $=  934.13$

Price of the Bond 2 $=  791.36$

Portfolio value before the rate hike $= 1,853.19$

Portfolio value after the rate hike  $= 1,725.49$

Intuitively it is correct because a rise in YTM reduces the price according to price yield relationship.

Goodluck

Comment: you are welcome!!